# Cake : failed to open stream() permissions

Tags: cakephp, vagrant

I have moved to a vagrant environment for developing a CakePhp site.
When viewing the new site there is a permission error with the log files.

Several log files are not writeable, with the following being an example output:

```
Warning (2): file_put_contents(/var/www/html/logs/error.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/src/Log/Engine/FileLog.php, line 133]
```

I have been using puPHPet to generate vagrant configs.

My config file (`config.yaml`) includes the following:

```
mount_options:
    dir_mode: '0777'
    file_mode: '0777'
```

When I SSH into the box and run `ls -al` i see the following:

```sh
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant       0 May 16 16:21 logs/
```

and:

```sh
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant vagrant 12152 May 16 16:53 cli-debug.log*
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant vagrant  2763 May 16 16:53 cli-error.log*
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant vagrant     0 May 16 14:12 empty*
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant vagrant     0 May 16 14:12 error.log*
```

While they are owned by `vagrant`, they seem to have 777 permissions and thus should be writeable by any user.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-rwxrwxr--` is 755 permission, not 777. Anyone other than `vagrant` and users in the `vagrant` group will be able to read, but not write.

Comment: Good knowledge. Never was a linux boss. I'll update the thread with that change and if that fixes it I'll mark as resolved, and add the update.

Comment: look here: https://github.com/salines/vagrant-cakephp/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L47

Comment: Can confirm that the permissions seem to be set in a few places so this was confusing me. Much appreciated all. Will upvote and close.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant sets it's permissions a little confusingly. Following feedback I've updated these permissions.
This now works as expected.

Thanks to Salines and Greg Schmidt.